# angular reactive form control setValue method not working every time for select control

Tags: angular, angular5, mdb-select

**Descreption**

I am facing strange issue with `angular` reactive form control **setValue** method `mdb-select`. when is it binding first time then it is working fine. but whenever **kpisCaptionValues** variable object is updated from **dataFilterService.widgetRequestObjectObservable** then after when i am setting value from code from **kpisPreviewClick** method as in a code. then it is not working. while setting value I am able to debug that I am passing correct value to **currentSelectetKpi** form control but inside **currentSelectetKpi.valueChanges.subscribe** value displaying undefined. just unable to know that why it's getting undefined. If any one have faced the same issue then please share with me.

**Component Code**

```
export class LineKpisChartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {      
    //local variable
    kpisCaptionValues: ValueLabelDictionary[] = [];

    //Form Controls 
    majorKpiForm: FormGroup;
    currentSelectetKpi: FormControl;

    ngOnInit() {     
        this.createFormControls();
        this.createForm();
        this.majorKpiForm.controls.currentSelectetKpi.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
            //this.bindKpisChanges(); 
        });
    }

    ngOnChanges() {        
        // subscribe observable when filter changed
        this.widgetRequestSubscription = this.dataFilterService.widgetRequestObjectObservable            
            .subscribe(response => {                
                this.getLineKpisDetails();                
            });
    }

    getLineKpisDetails(){
        this.kpisCaptionValues = [];
        this.getLineKpisDetailsSubscription = this.analyticsDashboardService.getLineKpisDetails<AreaKpisResponseAreaKpiValue>(lineKpisRequest, this.lineKpisChartConfig.getKpisUrl).subscribe(response => {
            this.kpisCaptionValues = response.Kpis.map((currElement, index) => {
                return { value: index.toString(), label: currElement.caption };
            });
        }), error => {
            console.log("Error in 'getLineKpisDetails' method : " + error);
            this.dataExists = AnalyticsDataExists.NotExistsForLastThreeYears;
        }               
    }

    createFormControls() {
        this.currentSelectetKpi = new FormControl();
    }

    createForm() {
        this.majorKpiForm = new FormGroup({
            currentSelectetKpi: this.currentSelectetKpi
        });
    }

    kpisPreviewClick(index: number) {                
        this.majorKpiForm.controls.currentSelectetKpi.setValue(index.toString());
    }
}
```

**Html code**

```
<mdb-select formControlName="currentSelectetKpi" [options]="kpisCaptionValues" placeholder="Choose" class="border-bottom-none a-hoverable w-auto"></mdb-select>
```

Comment: where is your `bindKpisChanges()` function ?

Comment: @SunilSingh I have updated the question please check now

Comment: What is `mdb-select` the tag has only one question and no definition. Can you make a small runnable reproduction on stackblitz please ? (You are maybe setting an invalid value)

Comment: @ibenjelloun Please find an example and description here about mdb-select https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/forms/material-select/